# Length of a segment in a triangle and tangent of an angle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given $\Delta$$ABC$ with $AB$$\bot$$BC$, $BD$ is the altitude to $AC$, $AF$ bisects angle $BAC$, $AP=12$ , and $PF=8$. Find $\tan(\angle BAF$) and find $PD$.

[image]

**Efforts made:** I've tried to apply angle bisector theorem but i couldn't get anything usefull ,and i've also tried to add some lines such as $FD$ but it didn't help me much though.

**Note:** I don't want the solution to the problem,only hints.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $BC=a,CA=b,AB=c$.

> I don't want the solution to the problem,only hints

I think you can get the answers using the followings :

- Since $AF$ bisects angle $BAC$, we have $AB:AC=BF:FC$ from which we can represent $BF,FC$ by $a,b,c$.
- The area of $\triangle{ABC}$ equals $\frac 12\times AB\times BC=\frac 12\times BD\times AC$ from which we can represent $BD$ by $a,b,c$.
- Since $\triangle{DAP}$ is similar to $\triangle{BAF}$, we can represent $DA$ by $c$.
- Since $\triangle{CBA}$ is similar to $\triangle{CDB}$, using $b^2-a^2=c^2$, we can represent $c$ by $b$, and $a$ by $b$ from which we can get $\tan(\angle{BAF})$.
- Having $\cos(\angle{BAF})$ leads to $c$ and $PD$.

Comment: Thanks for the hints,one question: From your first hint  how can you represent $FC$ by $a,b,c$ ?

Comment: @Jhon: Since $c:b=BF:FC$, i.e. $c:b=a-FC:FC$, we have $FC=\frac{ab}{b+c}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

Length of angle bisector at angle $  $A$ = \dfrac {2 b c }{ b+c} \cos A/2, $ with opposite sides $BD$ and $ BC$,

Similarity of triangles within a right angled triangle with results like $ AB^2 = AD\cdot AC, $

and, algebraic manipulations.

RESULTS:

$ \tan BAF = \frac12 $

$ PD\approx  5.36656.$